# Can random variables be something else other then discrete or continuous?

Tags: probability, random-variables, solution-verification

My textbook asks me the following question as a concept check:

Do you think that there are random variables which are neither discrete nor continuous? If yes, try to
construct a simple example. If no, then discuss why not.

I wrote No, how else can outcomes be measured if they aren't finite or countably infinite (which falls under discrete random variables) or if they can't be measured using a range of values (which falls under continuous random variables)? So the answer is no.

My question is, am I right? Can a random variable be described as something other then discrete or continuous? I don't think so based off my reasoning above, but I could be wrong and I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me whether I have this concept check right.

Comment: How exactly are “discrete” and “continuous” defined?

Comment: In my book discrete is defined as if the set of real numbers associated with the random variable are finite or countably infinite, and continuous is defined as if the set of real numbers associated with the random variable must fall within a certain range

Comment: That definition of "continuous random variable" seems kind of vague. Why aren't discrete variables a subset of continuous variables? I'm no expert, I'm just guessing that under some reasonable definitions, the sum of a discrete variable and a continuous variable is neither discrete nor continuous. Maybe a continuous r.v. should have a continuous cumulative distribution function? In that case, if the variable is not discrete, but its c.d.f. has some jumps, then it's not continuous either?

Comment: The bof comment is correct.  Random variables that are neither discrete nor continuous are often called "mixed."  Continuous random variables are sometimes defined as those that have a continuous CDF function, and other times defined as those that both have a continuous CDF function and a real-valued PDF (it just depends on the textbook).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it can, by a simple coin toss.

For example, let $X$ be a discrete distribution and $Y$ be a continuous distribution. Define the random variable $Z$ to be as follows : let $H$ be an independent (of $X$ and $Y$) Bernoulli-$\frac 12$ random variable, and define $Z = X$ if $H=0$ and $Z= Y$ if $H=1$.

Clearly $Z$ is not discrete or continuous (can be easily proven, since there are points which alone have non-zero probability by themselves, but not every point has this property as well), you may describe it as half of each. That gives rise to what is called as a mixed distribution.

---

The sentence "No, how can outcomes be measured ... variables)?" in your second paragraph misses the fact that an outcome , or event, need not just be a range or a set of points, but could be a mixture of both (for example, the speed of my car is either $10, 20$ or between $30$ and $40$) and hence be measured by breaking into these parts.

---

If one thinks of continuous random variables as those having an associated "density function" (PDF/CDF) as is usually the case, then funnily enough there is an entire class of distributions which aren't discrete, continuous, or even a mix of these. These are the *singular* distributions, the most well-known example being the Cantor distribution. This is not discrete (in terms of points having weights) or continuous (in terms of having a PDF/CDF) but is still a probability distribution. The buck stops here, though : every probability distribution is a mixture of a singular, continuous, and a discrete distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have bijective mixed function in just complete space.

f(x) = ⌊x⌋ + 1/2 + sgn-parity(x - ⌊x⌋) × (x - ⌊x⌋) /2

The sgn-parity gives positive or negative identity dependent on parity of the significancy of x. Rational x gives unequivocal parity and discrete points but irrational x is a superposition state.

The example show how random distribution could be useful as mixed continuity.